# Can I make a Fluent NHibernate foreign key convention which includes parent key name?

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, naming-conventions

I have a database schema where the convention for a foreign key's name is:

```
ForeignTable.Name + ForeignTable.PrimaryKeyName
```

So, for a `Child` table referencing a `Parent` table with a primary key column named `Key`, the foreign key will look like `ParentKey`.

Is there a way to create this convention in my Fluent NHibernate mapping?

Currently I'm using a `ForeignKeyConvention` implementation like this:

```
public class ForeignKeyNamingConvention : ForeignKeyConvention
{
    protected override string GetKeyName(PropertyInfo property, Type type)
    {
        if (property == null)
        {
            // Relationship is many-to-many, one-to-many or join.
            if (type == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("type");

            return type.Name + "ID";
        }

        // Relationship is many-to-one.
        return property.Name + "ID";
    }
}
```

This works exactly as I want for all types which have "ID" as a primary key. What I would like to do is replace the constant "ID" with the name of the primary key of the type being referenced.

If this isn't currently possible with Fluent NHibernate, I'm happy to accept that answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can get the `Mapping<T>` for a class, you can get the name of its Id column.

```
public class MyForeignKeyConvention: ForeignKeyConvention
{
    public static IList<IMappingProvider> Mappings = new List<IMappingProvider>();

    protected override string GetKeyName( System.Reflection.PropertyInfo property, Type type )
    {
        var pk = "Id";

        var model = new PersistenceModel();
        foreach( var map in Mappings ) {
            model.Add( map );
        }

        try {
            var mymodel = (IdMapping) model.BuildMappings()
                .First( x => x.Classes.FirstOrDefault( c => c.Type == type ) != null )
                .Classes.First().Id;

            Func<IdMapping, string> getname = x => x.Columns.First().Name;
            pk = getname( mymodel );
        } catch {
        }

        if (property == null) {
            return type.Name + pk;
        }
        return type.Name + property.Name;
    }
}
```

We can get the Mapping object with a little bit of plumbing.

The constructors of `ClassMap<T>` can pass `this` into our collection of Mappers.

For `AutoMapping<T>`, we can use Override as follows.

```
.Mappings( m => m.AutoMappings.Add( AutoMap.AssemblyOf<FOO>()
    .Override<User>( u => {
        u.Id( x => x.Id ).Column( "UID" );
        MyForeignKeyConvention.Mappings.Add( u );
    }
)
```

Comment: @Programming Hero this is all inspired by the unit test IdConventionTests.ColumnShouldntBeOverwritten

Comment: It's not as direct a solution as I'd have liked, but there's more than enough information for me to explore into. Thank you.

Comment: Had to change this.  But works, thank you.  Upvote.               /*protected override string GetKeyName(System.Reflection.PropertyInfo property, Type type)
        {*/
        protected override string GetKeyName(Member property, Type type)
        {

Comment: My (FluentNHibernate) version (that necessitated the change) : 1.3.0.733

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at [conventions](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Auto_mapping) and especially at implementing a custom foreign key convention.

---

UPDATE:

Here's an example. Assuming the following domain:

```
public class Parent
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public virtual string Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

which needs to be mapped to this schema:

```
create table Child(
    Id integer primary key, 
    ParentId integer
)

create table Parent(
    Id integer primary key
)
```

you could use this convention:

```
public class CustomForeignKeyConvention : IReferenceConvention
{
    public void Apply(IManyToOneInstance instance)
    {
        instance.Column(instance.Class.Name + "Id");
    }
}
```

and to create the session factory:

```
var sf = Fluently
    .Configure()
    .Database(
        SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.UsingFile("data.db3").ShowSql()
    )
    .Mappings(
        m => m.AutoMappings.Add(AutoMap
            .AssemblyOf<Parent>()
            .Where(t => t.Namespace == "Entities")
            .Conventions.Add<CustomForeignKeyConvention>()
        )
    )
    .BuildSessionFactory();
```

Comment: `ForeignKeyConvention` is where I started looking, but the lack of clear documentation makes it hard to understand where to find the relevant information from the parent type.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but it doesn't address my issue: Within `Apply(IManyToOneInstance)` how can you obtain the name of the parent key column? Name + "ID" isn't the behaviour I want. Name + Parent.KeyName is.

Comment: There's no such notion as PrimaryKeyName. It's all about conventions. By convention all primary key columns should be called `Id`. You could change this default behavior by implementing an `IIdConvention` for given types or all types, meaning that you already know the types for which this default behavior has been changed. As a consequence in the `IReferenceConvention` depending on the type you may apply the proper suffix.

Comment: My conventions don't demand a consistent primary key name between tables, but foreign keys are always `ForeignTable.Name` + `ForeignTable.PrimaryKeyName`. If this concept is not something the current conventions model can provide, I'm happy to have an answer say so.

Answer (score 1):

**For a system wide convention I believe this would serve the purpose best.**
( I wasn't sure whether to include the whole text or just a portion here, since I answered it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21728431/878612) already)

Here's the solution with links to current Fluent NHibernate & automapping documentation.

### **The issue (a simple example):**

Say you have the simple example (from fluent's wiki) with an Entity and it's Value Objects in a List:

```
public class Product
{
  public virtual int Id { get; set; }
  //..
  public virtual Shelf { get; set; }
}

public class Shelf
{
  public virtual int Id { get;  set; }
  public virtual IList<Product> Products { get; set; }

  public Shelf()
  {
    Products = new List<Product>();
  }
}
```

With tables which have e.g.

```
Shelf 
id int identity

Product 
id int identity 
shelfid int
```

And a foreign key for shelfid -> Shelf.Id

---

You would get the error:
**invalid column name ... shelf_id**

---

### **Solution:**

Add a convention, it can be system wide, or more restricted.

```
ForeignKey.EndsWith("Id")
```

**Code example:**

```
var cfg = new StoreConfiguration();
var sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
  .Database(/* database config */)
  .Mappings(m =>
    m.AutoMappings.Add(
      AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Product>(cfg)
          .Conventions.Setup(c =>
              {
                  c.Add(ForeignKey.EndsWith("Id"));
              }
    )
  .BuildSessionFactory();
```

Now it will automap the `ShelfId` column to the `Shelf` property in `Product`.

---

### More info

[Wiki for Automapping](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Auto-mapping)

```
Table.Is(x => x.EntityType.Name + "Table")
PrimaryKey.Name.Is(x => "ID")
AutoImport.Never()
DefaultAccess.Field()
DefaultCascade.All()
DefaultLazy.Always()
DynamicInsert.AlwaysTrue()
DynamicUpdate.AlwaysTrue()
OptimisticLock.Is(x => x.Dirty())
Cache.Is(x => x.AsReadOnly())
ForeignKey.EndsWith("ID")
```

[See more about Fluent NHibernate automapping conventions](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Conventions)